# Meteor reactivity in functions when session changes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I have this function, which is called manually when an event comes on, for example `click`, I need to call this method every time I click so it runs... But I want that function to be called automatically every time `Session.get('activeDecision)` changes so I wont need to call it on every event as events actually do `Session.set('activeDecision', value')`

This is my function

```
this.showResults = ->
  if Session.get("activeDecision")
    $(document).mousemove Meteor.rotatePointer
    $decisionId = Session.get("activeDecision")._id
    decisionDiv = "#" + $decisionId
    if decisionIsVoted($decisionId)
      opcion_roja_total = Session.get("activeDecision").redTotal
      opcion_azul_total = Session.get("activeDecision").blueTotal
      if (parseInt(opcion_roja_total) + parseInt(opcion_azul_total)) > 0
        percentage1 = Math.round((parseInt(opcion_azul_total) * 100) / (parseInt(opcion_roja_total) + parseInt(opcion_azul_total)))
        percentage2 = Math.round((parseInt(opcion_roja_total) * 100) / (parseInt(opcion_roja_total) + parseInt(opcion_azul_total)))
      else
        percentage1 = 0
        percentage2 = 0
      $(percentage: 0).animate
        percentage: percentage1
      ,
        duration: 1000
        easing: "swing"
        step: ->
          $(decisionDiv + " .blue-choice .percentage span").html Math.ceil(@percentage) + "%"

      $(percentage: 0).animate
        percentage: percentage2
      ,
        duration: 1000
        easing: "swing"
        step: ->
          $(decisionDiv + " .red-choice .percentage span").html Math.ceil(@percentage) + "%"

      $(decisionDiv + " .option").fadeOut "fast", ->
        $(decisionDiv + " .result").fadeIn "slow"

    else
      $(decisionDiv + " .result").fadeOut "fast", ->
        $(decisionDiv + " .option").fadeIn "slow"
```

if I do not call this method manually, it wont run even if Session changes... How can I handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to use a [template autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun). Something like:

```
Template.home.onRendered ->
  @autorun showResults
```

`showResults` will then be evaluated every time its reactive variables change, and the `autorun` will be automatically cleaned up when the template is destroyed.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I wanted to know :) Thank you